# html email not showing responsive

Tags: html, css, email, responsive-design, html-email

I'm using width=100% and max-width=600px on all the table tags but the email is taking the whole screen size (larger than 600px) when the screen size is larger. Basically it looks like it's just responding to width 100%. Any ideas to help keep this email responsive but also not show on the screen larger than 600px? I want it to show at the most 600px wide but scale smaller to fit all screens.

code:

```
<body>
<!-- Email Wrapper -->
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" max-width="600"style="border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #F2F2F2; height: 100% !important;width: 100% !important;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top" style="margin: 0;padding: 20px;border-top: 0;height: 100% !important;width: 100% !important;">
<!-- Container -->
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" max-width="600"style="border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #FFFFFF;border-top: 0;border-bottom: 0;">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
        <!-- Preheader -->
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" max-width="600" style="border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #FFFFFF;border-top: 0;border-bottom: 0;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td valign="top" style="padding-top: 9px;padding-left: 18px;padding-bottom: 9px;padding-right: 0;color: #606060;font-family: Helvetica, sans-serf;font-size: 11px;line-height: 125%;text-align: left;">Forum Group Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
                <td valign="top" style="padding-top: 9px;padding-left: 9px;padding-bottom: 9px;padding-right: 18px;color: #606060;font-family: Helvetica, sans-serf;font-size: 11px;line-height: 125%;text-align: right;"><a href="#" style="color: #606060">view in browser</a></td>
              </tr>  
            </tbody>
          </table>
<!-- End Preheader -->
          <!-- Preheader Spacer-->
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" max-width="600" style="border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #FFFFFF;border-top: 0;border-bottom: 0;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td valign="top" style="padding-top: 9px;padding-left: 18px;padding-bottom: 9px;padding-right: 0;color: #606060;"></td>
                <td valign="top" style="padding-top: 9px;padding-left: 9px;padding-bottom: 9px;padding-right: 18px;color: #606060;"></td>
              </tr>  
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <!-- End Preheader Spacer-->
          <!-- Header Image-->
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" max-width="600" style="border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #FFFFFF;border-top: 0;border-bottom: 0;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center">
                  <img src="img/logo-forum-group.png" max-width="286" max-height="115" border="0" alt="The Forum Group Logo">
                </td>
              </tr>  
            </tbody>
          </table>
<!-- Header Spacer-->
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" max-width="600" style="border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #FFFFFF;border-top: 0;border-bottom: 0;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td valign="top" style="padding-top: 9px;padding-left: 18px;padding-bottom: 9px;padding-right: 0;color: #606060;"></td>
                <td valign="top" style="padding-top: 9px;padding-left: 9px;padding-bottom: 9px;padding-right: 18px;color: #606060;"></td>
              </tr>  
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <!-- Header Strip-->
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" max-width="600" style="border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #eef0f6;border-top: 0;border-bottom: 0;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td valign="top" style="padding-top: 9px;padding-left: 18px;padding-bottom: 9px;padding-right: 0;color: #202020;font-family: Helvetica, sans-serf;font-size: 30px;line-height: 125%;text-align: left; text-transform: uppercase;">The Forum Group</td>
              </tr>  
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" max-width="600" style="border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #eef0f6;border-top: 0;border-bottom: 0;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td valign="top" style="padding-top: 9px;padding-left: 20px;padding-bottom: 15px;padding-right: 20px;color: #202020;font-family: Helvetica, sans-serf;font-size: 14px;line-height: 100%;text-align: left;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
              </tr>  
            </tbody>
          </table>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" max-width="600" style="border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #eef0f6;border-top: 0;border-bottom: 0;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td valign="top" style="padding-top: 9px;padding-left: 20px;padding-bottom: 9px;padding-right: 20px;color: #202020;font-family: Helvetica, sans-serf;font-size: 14px;line-height: 100%;text-align: left;"><a style="background-color:#3D87F5; color:#fff;border-radius:5px; padding:10px;text-decoration: none;" href="#">Read More</a></td>
              </tr>  
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <!-- Header Spacer blue-->
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" max-width="600" style="border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #eef0f6;border-top: 0;border-bottom: 0;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td valign="top" style="padding-top: 10px;color: #202020;font-size: 14px;line-height: 100%;"></td>
              </tr>  
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <!-- Header Spacer white--> 
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" max-width="600" style="border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #FFFFFF;border-top: 0;border-bottom: 0;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td valign="top" style="padding-top: 9px;padding-left: 18px;padding-bottom: 9px;padding-right: 0;color: #606060;"></td>
                <td valign="top" style="padding-top: 9px;padding-left: 9px;padding-bottom: 9px;padding-right: 18px;color: #606060;"></td>
              </tr>  
            </tbody>
          </table>
 </tr>  
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <!-- End Container -->
 </td>
</tr>  
</tbody>
</table>
<!-- End Email Wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I do not understand why do you have so many tables and what "email" container are you talking about?

Comment: Change the width to 600px and not 100%.

Comment: I know tables are annoying but it looks like that's the best option for creating html emails.

Comment: You have to do inline style for email html @MaihanNijat

Comment: @CarolMcKay Thanks for information. Just added into my knowledge :)

Comment: I am happy to contribute @MaihanNijat I have learnt so much from Stack Overflow, a good additional knowledge source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" max-width="600px"style="border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #F2F2F2; height: 100% !important;width: 100% !important; width: 500px;">
```

With:

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #F2F2F2; height: 100% !important; max-width:600px !important;">
```